# NLog writing to log file does not preserve string format

Tags: c#, nlog

According to the documentation and what everyone else does it should be possible to use a String.Format() approach when writing to the log file. For example, from the documentation:

```
int k = 42;
int l = 100;

logger.Trace("Sample trace message, k={0}, l={1}", k, l);
```

I have the following code:

```
Logger.Info("Server={0}, Port={1}, Interval(ms)={2}, Username={3}, Checking folder={4}", 
              Config.Server, Config.Port, Config.Username, Config.CSVFolder);
```

... however the output in the log file is:

```
2016-11-15 11:40:32.4472 INFO Server={0}, Port={1}, Interval(ms)={2}, Username={3}, Checking folder={4}
```

In other words the parameters have not been replaced. There are correct values in Config.Server etc, being string, int, string, string respectively.

I can't see anything else I should be doing from the documentation or examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only wrong thing I can see is the wrong number of parameters... maybe NLog doesn't work if the are not the same?

Comment: I addition, NLog is using `String.Format` internally so it's limited to the boundaries of that method. `String.Format` throws a `FormatException` when there is a argument missing. (this should be visible in the internal log of NLog)